# How to get the page back and not refresh after submitting form in django

Tags: javascript, html, django

reffering to my title above:

patientdetails.html

```
<form id="content" action="{% url patientdetails_view pk %}" method="post" > 
{% csrf_token %}{{form.owner}}
------
<tbody><tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Save" >   
------
```

patientList.html

```
{% for patient in patienter %}
<tr class = {% cycle "row_even" "row_odd" %}>
<td>{{ patient.id }}</td>
<td> <a href="#">{{ patient.Personnummer }}</a></td>
<td class ="name"> <a href=" {% url patientdetails_view patient.id %}">{{ patient.first_name }} {{ patient.last_name }}</a></td>

{% endfor %}
```

here is my question

My program flow like this. I have to click to a list of names in patientList.html and edit some data in patientdetails.html and after i made the changes how do i get back to patientList.html after i have done some changes in patientdetails.html and save. i have to click twice to get back to the original page. the first click refreshing and save the data and the second click back to the original page.

1. why is it doing that. what did i missing here.
2. how do i do alert stated"Data are saved".

I'm very very new to django. I'm totally lost in here.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to a url after completion of your form processing in the view that handles patient detail updates. You can use `HttpResponseRedirect()` to do this. This is very basic in django refer docs [Using a form in a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#using-a-form-in-a-view)

For #2, you can make use of [django messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) to pass messages. Through templates you can show a message wherever you feel appropriate.